# Выборка данных из Mysql по id

Tags: c#, mysql

Какой запрос Mysql нужно написать чтобы извлечь данные по id которые выделены на скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Максимум что я мог придумать это извлечение по id всю нужную таблицу. Но вот как извлечь именно значение wp_capabilities и wp_user_level не знаю.

```
class connect_to_bd
    {
        public string table1 { get; set; }
        public string table2 { get; set; }
        
    }

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Тут строка подключения к бд...");
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT* FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = 10";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (datareader.Read())
            {
                connect_to_bd.table1 = datareader["meta_key"].ToString();
                connect_to_bd.table2 = datareader["meta_value"].ToString();
            
            }
            datareader.Close();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Вы всё правильно делаете, только затираете предыдущие данные новыми. Добавляйте данные в коллекцию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  мне нужно извлечь именно значение wp_capabilities и wp_user_level

Comment: Вы получаете эти значения из БД. Но потом затираете другими. На показанном скриншоте 5 значений с user_id = 10. Вы получаете их все.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в том то и дело что я получаю их все. Мне нужно именно получить только два значения wp_capabilities и wp_user_level

Comment: Вставьте внутри цикла: `Console.WriteLine(datareader["meta_key"]);` - убедитесь, что вы получаете нужные значения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вообще я использую ListBox и привязку к классу. Но я идею понял вашу, сейчас попробую

Comment: Поздравляю! / Ещё раз: вы в цикле получаете минимум 5 (**пять**) значений (или больше - не видно, сколько их с айдишником 10). Но вы их заносите в один и тот же экземпляр класса. Последующие значения затирают предыдущие. Создайте коллекцию (например, List<connect_to_bd>) и добавляйте в неё. Потом её привяжите к листбоксу.

Comment: Вывод Console.WriteLine можно посмотреть в окне Output Студии.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116495/discussion-between-tand-and-alexander-petrov).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov запрос долго выполняется в любом случае. Я отписал в чате